# Reduce a Ruby array of hashes

Tags: ruby, generics, ruby-2.0

I have an `array` of `hash` values:

```
> taxes = [{:name=>"foo", :rate=>0.5}, {:name=>"bar", :rate=>2.5}] 
=> [{:name=>"foo", :rate=>0.5}, {:name=>"bar", :rate=>2.5}]
```

This works to summarize the rates:

```
> taxes.reduce(0) {|sum,element|sum + element[:rate]}
=> 3.0
```

Is there another way to do this that might be more understandable and succinct?

** edit **

For comparison (yes, I realize that this is just an array):

```
>> [1,2,3].reduce(:+)
=> 6
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got? Do you want something shorter?

Comment: Do you like `taxes.collect { |h| h[:rate] }.reduce(0,:+) # => 3.0` ?

Comment: There's a difference between text being incomprehensible and a reader being merely unfamiliar with something. Functional notation is not only very succinct, but can become the most comprehensible notation once the reader is familiar with the functional concepts.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: `inject` seems worse to me.

Comment: craig: This is about as succinct as it's going to get. @Platinum is right.

Comment: @Linuxios: I guess I don't like the `reduce(0)` bit.

Comment: @craig: `reduce` is a synonym for `inject`, if you find that clearer.

Comment: @craig in Rails, you can use Enumerable#sum like this: `taxes.sum{|item| item[:rate]}`

Comment: Of course... behind the scenes that's just using `reduce` :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe using the common "map" and "reduce" functions is more clear?

```ruby
taxes.map { |t| t[:rate] }.reduce(:+) # => 3.0
```

Comment: Frankly I find this more confusing.  I see nothing wrong with the original version.

Comment: @nzifnab: ya, this question is subjective.

Comment: I believe this solution is slower because it iterates twice, one the map and other the reduce. I am right?

Comment: @Rafa: definitely, a plain "reduce" solution is best IMHO.